# AS3 How to hitTest with multiple Movie Clips of the same Instance Name?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, flashdevelop

Hey everyone so I have a Movie Clip inside my `platforms` movie clip called `mcTaco` so `platforms.mcTaco`. I add the `platforms` and the `player` which I check for hitTest collisions to the stage dynamically using code. When I check for the `player` and `platforms.mcTaco` collison everything works fine. It's when I duplicate the `mcTaco` creating multiple instances of them inside the `platforms` movieclip that I am having the main issues.

I know I have to add them to an array and use a for loop to check for the hitTest of the multiple `platforms.mcTaco` instances but I don't know how to accomplish this. I am using an IDE Flash Develop for my code and here is what I have so far:

I add my Platforms to the stage like so:

```
//ADD PLATFORMS AND ENVIRONMENT
    private function addPlatForms():void
    {
        //Add Obstacle Platforms
        platforms = new mcPlatforms();
        platforms.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 80;
        platforms.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) + 165;
        addChildAt(platforms, 1);
        aPlatformArray.push(platforms);
        //trace(aPlatformArray.length + " NPLATFORMS");
    }
```

and my Player:

```
//Add Character
        player = new mcPlayer();
        player.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 80;
        player.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) + 78;
        addChildAt(player, 1);
```

and in my ENTER_FRAME Event Listener I am doing this to test the `player` and `platforms.mcTaco` hitTest like so:

```
private function tacoHitTestHandler():void 
    {
        if (player.hitTestObject(platforms.mcTaco))
        {
            platforms.mcTaco.visible = false;
            trace("HIT TACO");
        }
    }
```

I just need some help on figuring out how to go about doing this. I have my Taco Array`private var aTacoArray:Array;` instantiated but I just don't know how to push the `platforms.mcTaco` Movie clips into it to use the for loop to test it. Any help on how to go about doing this would be greatly appreciated. I just don't want to have to do the `if (player.hitTestObject(platforms.mcTaco1) || player.hitTestObject(platforms.mcTaco2) etc...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop children inside each of the platforms to get all tacos by their class or/and name.

```
private function tacoHitTestHandler():void 
{
    // Loop through the list of the platforms.
    for (var i:int = 0; i < aPlatformArray.length; i++)
    {
        // Get a platform instance from the Array.
        var aPlatform:mcPlatforms = aPlatformArray[i];

        // Loop through the children of a platform.
        for (var j:int = 0; j < aPlatform.numChildren; j++)
        {
            // Get a potential taco.
            var aTaco:mcTaco = aPlatform.getChildAt(j) as mcTaco;

            // Skip if it is not a taco.
            if (!aTaco) continue;

            // Ignore invisible objects.
            if (!aTaco.visible) continue;

            // Ignore wrong tacos by name.
            if (aTaco.name != "mcTaco") continue;

            // Hit test against taco.
            if (player.hitTestObject(aTaco))
            {
                aTaco.visible = false;
                trace("HIT TACO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes.

First, calling a class **mcTaco** and giving the same instance name **mcTaco** is asking for headache because there are moments where your code will not be sure, if you are referring a class of a declared instance.

Second, call your classes with uppercase head letter because it's nice. A nice scottish **McTaco** would suffice.

Comment: Hey @Organis I appreciate you taking the time to help out but I don't think this would work. I have no problem working with Loops and Arrays. The answer you provided will remove my platforms that are added to the stage which is what I don't want. I want the nested movie clips inside the platforms ie 'mcTaco' to be removed and able to hitTest with the 'player' I have multiple instances of the 'mcTaco' nested inside the parent platforms that I want to be able to hitTest against.

Comment: @Nathan Ok, I see what you want to do now. Updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You push your tacos to the aTacoArray the same way you do it with platforms:

```
aTacoArray.push(myTacoMC);
```

Then you can loop trough them and test the collision on each:

```
private function tacoHitTestHandler():void 
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < aTacoArray.length; i++)
    {
        // get taco from array
        var currentTaco:MovieClip = aTacoArray[i];

        if (player.hitTestObject(currentTaco))
        {
            currentTaco.visible = false;
            trace("HIT TACO");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Philarmon thanks for the help. I just don't seem to understand how to push the nested movie clips 'mcTaco' inside the aTacoArray. The 'mcTaco' is a child of the Parent 'platforms' so would i do something like 'var tacos:MovieClip = platforms.mcTaco;' then push it in the aTacoArray? 'aTacoArray.push(tacos)'. Even though I have multiple instances of the 'mcTaco' nested inside the platforms? Will it add all 5 of the instances into the taco array?

Comment: Actually Organis' answer shows a way how to detect all tacos in your platforms (the inner for... loop). It will be faster to detect all of them once in the beginning, push them to an array and check the hittest against that rather than get them every time you call the hittest function

Comment: @Philarmon Normally, yes, it would be better to list all tacos and work with the single-dimension list. But if there are few enough tacos (below 1000, maybe 10000) it does not really matter as AS3 is fast enough. On desktops, anyway. Optimization, code refactoring and resolving performance bottlenecks require another level of programming skill anyway.